# Kali Linux Failed to launch preferred application for category “TerminalEmulator” and all files missing

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I installed 64bit Kali 2020.4 in vmware workstation pro.
After that, all I did was grant superuser permission to my current (default) user, and ran some updates via `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.
Everything went fine and I closed off the machine.

When I logged back in again, I was not able to access the terminal. Not from the panel, neither by right clicking and opening a termal from the desktop.
It shows an error

> Failed to launch preferred application for category "TerminalEmulator"

I also entered my file manager, and everything is empty there. How do I fix these?

Comment: You probably have not set it... Or you did not install it. Try CTRL-ALT-F1 or F2...F6 to access to the virtual consoles. See even [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/157621/196535). ps> -1 not mine HNY.

Comment: press ctrl+alt+f7 to exit from the login shell.

Comment: Installing `xfce4-settings` [fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65741967/failed-to-launch-preferred-application-for-category-terminalemulator) this for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem today. Installed Kali 2020.4 64-bit and ran `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` as you described. Rebooted the system and was [unable to open terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq3wE.png) or [browse files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFlH9.png) (I only tried via the "Home" folder on the desktop).

I was still able to open QTerminal directly from the application menu to run commands. I was able to fix this by running the following. Hopefully this works for you.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

This returned a list of [packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuW0d.png) that "were automatically installed and are no longer required:" Remove these packages with the below command.

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Reboot. Then run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` again. The following [packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZNCY.png) were required. Reboot again and terminal/file browsing should be working as expected.

I suspect one specific package "xfce4-helpers" is causing the issue. I'm new to Linux so not sure of the cause (hopefully someone can elaborate).

After completing the above steps, run `sudo apt-get install xfce4-helpers`.

---

After doing the above

- right click the terminal and remove it from panel
- then right click somewhere on the panel bar and go to "panel"
- next go to "Add New" then scroll down to verve terminal and click on it.
- Add it to the bar panel (it will show up next to notifications).
- Right click again and go to move and move it to where it was.
  (alternatively you can just go to app drop down menu and add Qterm to your desktop).

Answer (score 3):

By default, Thunar uses [the `exo-open` command](https://man.archlinux.org/man/extra/exo/exo-open.1.en), which is [configured in the XFCE settings](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/exo/preferred-applications). If you do not have the XFCE settings app installed, you can instead configure it in `~/.config/xfce4/helpers.rc`:

```
TerminalEmulator=konsole
TerminalEmulatorDismissed=true
```

or, another example,

```
TerminalEmulator=kitty
TerminalEmulatorDismissed=true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have functional terminal emulators on your machine but your launcher on the taskbar is pointing to an incorrect one after you've jiggered things around, try the following:

1. Right click the terminal launcher icon on your task bar.
   In the launcher window that opens, press the + icon to add new items to the launcher.
2. In the resulting dialog, there should be a text box to allow searching for items to add. Type in "term".
3. If there are any terminal emulators in the results, add one (or more).
4. Next time you click the launcher icon, the emulators you added will now execute.